# Executing out parameter MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

While executing following query

```
    DELIMITER  //
    create procedure usp_ItemView(
        p_itemname varchar(50),
        p_company varchar(50),
        p_model varchar(50),
        p_unit varchar(50),
        p_photo varchar(50),
        p_color varchar(50),
        p_size varchar(50),
        p_weight varchar(50),
        p_stock varchar(50),
        out p_maxsi int    
    )
    begin
        insert into item_tbl(
            item_name,company,model_no,unit,photo,
            color,size,weight,stock 
        )
        values(
            p_itemname,p_company,p_model,p_unit,p_photo,
            p_color,p_size,p_weight,p_stock
        );
        set p_maxsi = (select max(sl_no) from item_tbl);
        insert into stock(itemslno,quantity)
        values(
            p_maxsi,p_stock
        );
    end //
    DELIMITER ;
```

I get an error:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'itemslno' in 'field list'

Comment: does column `itemslno` exist on the `stock` table?

Comment: Does the stock table have a column called 'itemslno'?

Comment: ya i have.. i am shocked how this error has come..

Comment: what happens if you just execute `insert into stock(itemslno,quantity) values(0,0)` against the database - outside of this procedure

Comment: Is it possible to see the structure of the tables `item_tbl` and `stock`? Also, have you considered using [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get `p_maxsi`?